# VideoView пересоздается при возобновлении окна

Tags: android, videoview

Есть VideoView который играет видео с веб сервера, вот примерые куски кода:

```
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(sourceUrl));

          getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
          mediaController = new MediaController(this);
          mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

          videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

          videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
              public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
              {                 
                  videoView.requestFocus();
                  videoView.start();
                  mediaController.show();
              }
           });

    @Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mediaController.show();
            videoView.start();

}
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    videoView.pause();
}
```

Собственно, если свернуть программу кнопкой хоум, то при разворачивании она пересоздаст VideoView и начнет проигрывание сначала, есть идеи как исправить?
Кстати, при уходе в спящий режим из этого окна и возобновлении все работает отлично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Время от времени система должна вызывать метод onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) (Вы его должны переопределить). В этом методе сохраняйте свои значение, такие как позиция просмотра видео, положение скрола и так далее. Когда система пересоздаст Ваше окно (это штатная ситуация), то в вызывая метод protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) в бандле будет передан тот же intent. Теперь знания можно достать и корректно инициализировать компоненты.

Если по хорошему, то VideoView должен уметь сам все это запоминать, как делают другие элементы, но почему он  не делает... Но на самом то деле сохранить нужно позицию, урл и, может быть, громкость.

Да, не забывайте, сисема вызывает метод onSaveInstanceState обычно перед тем, как окно будет свернуто, но может вызывать и в другие моменты времени. Поэтому не стоит делать никаких предположений о том, когда и почему будет вызван метод.

Comment: Хм, в итоге ясно, но это же создаст новую проблему? Ведь вызов onCreate даже с прогрессом заставит VideoView заного закешировать кусок видео

Comment: раз пользователь свернул приложение, значит он понимает, что делает.
Система вполне сама может себе кешировать и не удалять сразу.
Если так сильно страшно за траффик, то можно вручную закачать видео и только потом давать смотреть (либо параллельно с закачкой).
Пользователи, которые сморят видео, обычно либо сидят на wifi, либо пользуются безлимитными (или с большим запасом) траффиками.
Стандартный браузер приблизительно также работает. А вот приложение Youtube позицию запоминает, но играть не всегда может - приходится тыкать старт-стоп.