# Проигрывание видео с места останова в MediaController

Tags: android, videoview

Доброго времени суток! Для кастомного `videoview` мне пришлось переопределить `MediaController` (чтобы изменить дизайн кнопок и подключить для кнопок `pause/play` свой селектор). Ситуация такая: поставив видео на паузу и свернув приложение, а потом опять восстановив, видео начинает проигрываться сначала, а не с того места, на котором было приостановлено, в связи с чем возник вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы видео начинало проигрываться с того места, на котором было остановлено? Что для этого в `MediaController` нужно изменить?

upgrade:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

VideoView videoView;

VkMediaController mc;

private static final String CURRENT = "duration";

private static final String URL = "url";

private Uri mURI;

private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.video_view_player);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewplayer);
    mc = new VkMediaController(this);
    mURI = getIntent().getData();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mURI = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString(URL));
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT);

    }
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(mURI);
    videoView.requestFocus();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    videoView.start();
    if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
        videoView.seekTo(mCurrentPosition);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(CURRENT, videoView.getCurrentPosition());
    outState.putString(URL, mURI.toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

Проблему я свою всё-таки решил.Стоило только более подробно прочесть документацию и уяснить, что  onSaveInstanceState годится в том случае, если при повороте экрана мне нужно сохранить данные Activity. В моём же случае нужно использовать  SharedPreferences, что я и сделал, и в итоге всё заработало. Вот код, если кому интересно:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity  {

VideoView videoView;

VkMediaController mc;

private Uri mURI;

private final static String CURRENT_POSITION  = "currentPosition";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.video_view_player);
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewplayer);
    mc = new VkMediaController(this);
    mURI = getIntent().getData();
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(mURI);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(videoView == null)
        return;
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(CURRENT_POSITION, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    videoView.seekTo(myPrefs.getInt(CURRENT_POSITION,videoView.getCurrentPosition()));
    videoView.start();

}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(CURRENT_POSITION, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).edit();
    myPrefs.putInt(CURRENT_POSITION, videoView.getCurrentPosition());
    myPrefs.commit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раньше я отвечал на очень похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/139428/android-videoview-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: спасибо за совет,воспользовался им,но искомой цели так и не достиг, может я что-то коряво сделал(код выше)?

Comment: Вы уверены, что `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` должен быть самым последним? В 99.99999% случаев, super метод вызывается самым первым. Если только не нужен мегахак.

Comment: Так я super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); пробовал уже первым вызывать - эффект один и тот же.Беда в том,что getCurrentPosition() почему-то возвращает ноль.

Comment: проблему решил